# How to make multi touch on Android?

Tags: multithreading, touch

I am using java, libgdx, box2d.

how to make multi touch? here is what I have so far. This works fine with single touch. I need to change this so it can handle multi touch.

if user touch left side of screen than do some thing. and if user touch right side of screen than do some thing else.

Problem is that if user touch left and right side of screen at same time than it will only do one thing.

I want to change it so if user touch left and right side of screen at same time than it will do 2 different things.

```
 if (GameKeys.isPressed()) {
            if (GameKeys.x < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) {
           //touch left side of screen and do some thing
     }
}

if (GameKeys.isPressed()) {
        if (GameKeys.x > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) {
         //touch right side of screen and do some thing      
       }
 }
```

//gameinputprocessor class

```
public class GameInputProcessor extends InputAdapter {

    public boolean mouseMoved(int x, int y) {
        GameKeys.x = x;
        GameKeys.y = y;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean touchDragged(int x, int y, int pointer) {
        GameKeys.x = x;
        GameKeys.y = y;
        GameKeys.down = true;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        GameKeys.x = x;
        GameKeys.y = y;
        GameKeys.down = true;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        GameKeys.x = x;
        GameKeys.y = y;
        GameKeys.down = false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

//gamekeys class

```
public class GameKeys {
    public static int x;
    public static int y;
    public static boolean down;
    public static boolean pdown;

    public static boolean isDown() {
        return down;
    }

    public static boolean isPressed() {
        return down && !pdown;
    }

    public static boolean isReleased() {
        return !down && pdown;
    }
}
```